# Aggregate values according to date granularity

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail, granularity

I am facing an issue I can't solve by my own.

I am working with time series. So I have date in column. The granularity can be YEAR, QUARTER & MONTH.

I wanted to know how to display the SUM of the LASTEST MONTH of the selected date granularity.

For example:

If we are displaying yearly data, I would like to see, for each year, the SUM of DECEMBER data
[image]

If we are displaying quarterly data, I would like to the SUM of MARCH data for Q1, The SUM of JUNE data for Q2 and so on.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help and feel free to ask any question if it's not clear ! :)

Regards,

Maxime

Comment: Very good question max! (y)

Answer (score 1):

Replicating it on sample superstore

Let's assume your desired measure is [sales] .  Create a CF like this

```
if month([Ship Date]) =
{EXCLUDE MONTH([Ship Date]) : max( MONTH([Ship Date]))}
then [Sales] END
```

Add this field instead of your chosen measure on the view and Voila.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

As required in the comments, if only months at quarter ends are required, use this calculation field instead

```
if month([Ship Date]) =
{EXCLUDE MONTH([Ship Date]) : max( MONTH([Ship Date]))} 
and month([Ship Date]) IN (3, 6, 9, 12)
then [Sales] END
```

Check your Tableau version.  Tableau introduced `IN` in its very later version.

Comment: Hi ! thank you very much for your help ! That is super useful and I learnt something. Nevertheless, it doesn't really execute what I want. In your example, for 2021, it will use January data because it s the latest available data. I would like to display Null or hide the missing data if possible. Do you an idea? :) (Btw, very nice birds pics, that's beautifull)

Comment: Yes @Max, that is calculated in that way only.  maximum of available dates.  At the moment, I cannot think of a strategy to do it in Tableau the way you want.  And thanks for having a look on my bird pic gallery. :)

Comment: Nice, I am new to Tableau so sorry if I sounds noob !
This is a nice solution but by doing this we are no longer able to see the MONTHLY data properly ^^

Comment: I mean, yes you see monthly data but only for Month in [3, 6, 9 ,12], the rest is NULL. So my point is, if we look at my initial question it doesn t work ! (sum the last available month for the current granularity: DEC for yearly data, MAR JUN SEP DEC for quarterly data and the month itself for monthly data !)

Comment: I'll check it again and revert